# When I create VirtualHost in .conf file and /etc/init.d/apache2 reload error

Tags: server, virtualbox, apache2, dns, virtualbox-networking

**My Task :** 
*The domain `www.mynewsite.lk` is configured and hosted in a hosting server with the IP address `192.168.1.100`. Another domain called `www.mysite.lk` should also be configured with the same content without any duplication. Here I want to configure the Apache server with name-based virtual hosting.*

First of all I Created directory which contains the file of my site and add 'home.html' file.

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/website
sudo vim /var/www/website/home.html
```

After I created new virtual host file as `default.conf` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` folder and it is look like

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.100>
     ServerAdmin webmast@new.lk
     DocumentRoot /var/www/website
     DirectoryIndex home.html
     ServerName www.mynewsite.lk
     Serveralias www.mysite.lk
     ErrorLog /var/log/error/website/error.log
     CustomLog combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Next I created directories to hold 'Error.log'

```
    sudo mkdir /var/log/error
    sudo mkdir /var/log/error/website
```

Then I set the DNS using `sudo vim /etc/hosts` and I added following line that file

```
    192.168.1.100 www.mysite.lk www.mynewsite.lk
```

After I enabled the `default.conf` file that I created using `sudo a2ensite default.conf` command

Then I run the this command

```
sudo ifconfig vmnet0: 192.168.1.100 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

And last I reloaded the apache server using `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload` command

I had an error as **Job for apache2.service failed. See 'systemctl status apache2.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details**.

what do I do to make this error...? Please help me to complete my task.
Is there an any error I created .conf `<VirtualHost>` ...?

Comment: I tried using that one. But I can't solve my error...

Comment: Solution would not be only re-installation of `apache2`, it might be configuration error.  I had also the same issue. Remove & reinstall apache2 didn't solve my problem but when i reinstall `libapache2-mod-mono`,  i got to know that i mis configured one file & it was simple grammatical error.

Comment: Error says itself that `See 'systemctl status apache2.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.` Did you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my error changing `default.conf` file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` folder and creating directories to hold 'Access.log' file.

So I created **VirtualHost** last line `CustomLog combined` changed as `CustomLog /var/log/access/website/access.log combined`

Then default.conf file was as follows...

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.100>
     ServerAdmin webmast@new.lk
     DocumentRoot /var/www/website
     DirectoryIndex home.html
     ServerName www.mynewsite.lk
     Serveralias www.mysite.lk
     ErrorLog /var/log/error/website/error.log
     CustomLog /var/log/access/website/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And I made directories to hold 'Access.log'

```
sudo mkdir /var/log/access
sudo mkdir /var/log/access/website
```

Then I could 'reload/start' my apache server without any errors. And I was able to run my home.html file using `www.mynewsite.lk` and `www.mysite.lk` which I created 'Virtual Host' links.